# Using MEAN Stack - Querying MongoDB and Passing Value as a Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

I'm using the MEAN stack to create a web app. I have my server.js, console.js, a MongoDB called 'contactlist', and an index.html that contains Javascript for a tree diagram. What I would like to do is query my MongoDB for say, a key, and return with its value (or really just grab any information). I'd like to then save that value as a variable and pass it along to the javascript contained in my index.html.

This is the closest I've gotten reconstructing a tutorial's code. Using mongojs as my driver, I have this in my server.js:

```
app.get('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
console.log("I received a GET request")

db.contactlist.find({email:"bob11@email.com"},function(err, docs) {
//looks at the contact list database for anything with the email of bob11@email.com
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
});
});
```

In my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
console.log("Hello World from controller");

var refresh = function() {
$http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    $scope.contactlist = response;
    $scope.contact = "";
});
};
```

The use of the ng-repeat function below is an artifact of the original application's use (display a list of all contacts). Now I just want one value, but I don't know what function to use. Here's my index.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <!-- grabs the name from parameters set out in server.js -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This displays the name ("Bob") of the email I filtered for (bob11@email.com) onto the webpage. At this point, even just being able to save that name as a variable and pass it along to the javascript would help. Ng-repeat is definitely not what I want to use, but I'm new to programming and the MEAN stack so I'm kind of stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: What result do you want ? If you just want to display one contact, simply :
    $scope.contact = response[0] or something and remove the ng repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, But I'll try to help out.

If you're asking how to edit the `contact.name` variable on the client, you should probably familiarize yourself with [Angular's two way data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04). This means that any change to $scope in the controller will affect the data displayed in the HTML, and any change to a variable in the html will be applied to $scope.

For example, if you want to edit the `contact.name` on a page, you could use an input text field bound to `contact.name` as its model. To do that, we'll need `ng-model` to make a bridge between the input field and the value we want to change. that might look something like this

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
      Name: <input type="text" ng-model="contact.name"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

We can then add an `ng-change` attribute to the input to perform an action on change. [See working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12475/)

Answer (score 0):

First solution:
you can use ng-init for in your html page and binding mechanism something like this

```
<div ng-init="param='value';">
    <div ng-controller="yourController" >
        <label>param: {{value}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

now whatever parameter you are using in html file is available to your controller function

```
function yourController($scope) {
        console.log($scope.param);
}
```

second solution:
you can make a service for passing the value in controller something like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('valuepassing', function() {

    var myvaluepassingService = {};
         data =[];
    myvaluepassingService.addvalue = function(value) {
        data.push(value);
    };
    myvaluepassingService.removevalue = function(value) {
        var index = data.indexOf(value);
        data.splice(index, 1);
    };
    myvaluepassingService.data = function() {
        return data;
    };

    return myvaluepassingService;
});

function MyCtrl($scope, valuepassing) {
    $scope.newvalue = {};
    $scope.valuepassing = valuepassing;    
}
```